# ¿Como enviar una petición HTTP a otro controlador en otro puerto?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

me gustaría saber como se puede enviar una petición HTTP desde un controlador a otro que se encuentra en otro proyecto y un puerto distinto.
Llevándolo a mi caso, lo que quiero hacer es que desde el controlador del proyecto 2, se mande una petición al controlador del proyecto 1 y se imprima en ese proyecto los valores, de momento en terminal.

Adjunto el código y los controladores:

**Proyecto 1 :**

- Entidad (es la misma en los dos proyectos):

  ```
  package hello;

  public class Pago {

      private final String dni;
      private final Double importe;
      private final String concepto;

      public Pago(String dni, Double importe, String concepto) {
          this.dni = dni;
          this.importe = importe;
          this.concepto = concepto;
      }

      public String getDni() {
          return dni;
      }

      public Double getImporte(){
          return importe;
      }

      public String getConcepto() {
          return concepto;
      }
  }
  ```
- Controlador:

  @RestController
  public class PagoController {

  ```
  @RequestMapping("/pago")
  public Pago pago(@RequestParam(value="dni") String dni, @RequestParam(value="importe") Double importe, 
      @RequestParam(value="concepto" , defaultValue="Pagamento de dietas") String concepto) {

          System.out.println("DNI: "+ dni +". Importe a pagar: " + importe + ". Concepto: "+concepto);
          return new Pago(dni, importe, concepto); 
      }

  }
  ```

**Proyecto 2:**

- Entidad: La misma que en proyecto 1
- Controlador:

  @RestController
     public class PagoController {

  ```
     @RequestMapping("/pago")
     public Pago pago(@RequestParam(value="dni") String dni, @RequestParam(value="importe") Double importe, 
      @RequestParam(value="concepto" , defaultValue="Pagamento de dietas") String concepto, 
      HttpServletResponse response)  throws ServletException, IOException {
          System.out.println("{dni= "+dni+" importe= "+importe+" concepto= "+concepto+"}");
          response.sendRedirect("localhost:8090/pago?dni="+dni+"&importe="+importe);
          return new Pago(dni,importe,concepto);
      }
  }
  ```

Un saludo y muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Es el navegador del cliente el que debe establecer esa conexión o el servidor? En caso de que sea el navegador del cliente, ¿has probado con enviar una cabecera `Location: https://tu_otro_servidor:otro_puerto/otra_ruta` junto con su código HTTP (por ejemplo, `301 Moved Permanently`)? En caso del servidor, échale un vistazo a la [documentación del cliente HTTP](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html).

Comment: Hola, ya hice el Location, como podrás ver ahora en el código del controlador del proyecto2, pero sigue sin funcionarme ya que en el otro proyecto no se printea nada por terminal. Como información adicional el proyecto 1 se lanza en el puerto 8090 y el 2 en el 8091. Lo que quiero es que si hago una petición a un controlador, que éste, se la reenvie al otro controlador. No se si redireccionando es la manera más correcta o hay otras formas. Un saludo y muchas gracias por responder :)

Comment: Acabo de ver tu edición y tu redirección es errónea. Estás ofreciendo una URL relativa y no absoluta (indiques o no el esquema explícitamente). Prueba con `response.sendRedirect("//localhost:8090/pago?dni="+dni+"&importe="+importe);`. Por otro lado, estás concatenado cadenas a URLs, no es buena idea si no controlas su contenido.